# Jquery Draggable/Droppable appending multiple divs

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I am trying to get a droppable area to accept multiple divs but it will only accept the most recently declared. I'm having trouble finding out how to go about this problem.

Here is the code:

```
$(".square").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
$(".rect").draggable({helper: 'clone'});

$("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: ".square",
    accept: ".rect",
    drop: function(ev,ui){
        $(ui.draggable).clone.appendTo(this);
```

Comment: We will need to see your HTML markup, as well.

Answer (score 5):

When you pass the `accept` option twice to a object the latest one will overwrite the first one

Try

```
$(".square").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
$(".rect").draggable({helper: 'clone'});

$("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: ".rect, .square",
    drop: function(ev,ui){
        $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bUcLA/)

Comment: may I ask you to take a look at a jQuery draggable and droppable related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498364/jquery-drag-and-drop-simulation-does-not-work-for-the-last-draggable ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use  "accept:" only once to define the selector of accepted elements

Answer (score 0):

You should try making a separate class from square and rect, such as "droppableShape". Then add it as a second class to each of them and just use one accept.

HTML

```
<...class="square droppableShape"..../>
<...class="rect droppableShape".../>
```

JQuery

```
$(".droppableShape").draggable({helper: 'clone'});

$("#canvas").droppable({
accept: ".droppableShape",
drop: function(ev,ui){
    $(ui.draggable).clone.appendTo(this);
```